# Running batch of emacs commands on file

Tags: emacs, batch-processing

to clean up some files, I need to perform a series of steps, the emacs code for these steps is

```el
(query-replace "," " " nil 
  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) 
    (region-beginning)) 
  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) 
    (region-end)))

(query-replace "1 1/4" "1.25" nil 
  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) 
    (region-beginning)) 
  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) 
    (region-end)))

(query-replace-regexp "[0-9][0-9][0-9]V[0-9][0-9][0-9] " "" nil 
  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) 
    (region-beginning)) 
  (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) 
    (region-end)))
```

(there's more, but you get the idea)
Is there a way to put all these commands in a file and run them? Or perhaps assign a name to them in a lisp file and run them by name?

Comment: Note that your `if` expressions are redundant. You are explicitly re-implementing the default behaviour of `query-replace`. `(query-replace "," " ")` is all you really need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this section of the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Command-Example.html#Command-Example).
Put all the stuff that you want to do in a mega-function `foo`.
Put that into `~/bar.el`.
Then this will do the job:

```
emacs --batch -l ~/bar.el -f foo
```

### UPD: a small example

Put into `~/bar.el`:

```
(defun foo ()
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (replace-regexp "foo" "bar")
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (replace-regexp "fred" "barney")
  (save-buffer))
```

Create a test file:

```
echo "Fred walks into a foo" > test.txt
```

Now test it:

```
emacs --batch -l ~/bar.el test.txt -f foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can I just place the individual functions in bar.el, (replace ...), or does everything need to be in a single function, foo? Also, can bar.el have interactive functions, so I can do a query-replace? Simple code sample would be much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: `query-replace` requires user input, so you can't run that in batch,
but you can use `replace-regexp`. I'll update the answer with some
sample code.

Comment: `(replace-regexp REGEXP TO-STRING &optional DELIMITED START END)` -- e.g., `(replace-regexp "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))`